# Is active recall testing more effective than passive study?

Tags: psychology, education, memory, learning

A claim made by [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html) is that:

> Research has shown that active recall testing is far more effective at building strong memories than passive study.

Definitions (from [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html)):

- **Active recall testing**: being asked a question and trying to remember the answer
- **Passive study**: where we read, watch or listen to something without pausing to consider if we know the answer

Is active recall testing more effective than passive study at building strong memories?